# Design layout with 4 squares in html and css

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

How to design the the following [image: layout] in html with bootstrap.
I'm trying to design it, but I can't design two columns with different heights
Here is the relevant code

```css
html, body{
  height:100%;
}
.row{
 margin:0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<span class="row">
 <span class="col-xs-5" style="background-color:#ED1C24;height:70%;">XXXX</span>
 <span class="col-xs-7" style="background-color:#FFF200;height:20%;">YYYY</span>
</span>

<span class="row" style="height:100%;">
 <span class="col-xs-5" style="background-color:#FF7F27;height:30%;">ZZZZ</span>
 <span class="col-xs-7" style="background-color:#22B14C;height:80%;">WWWW</span>
</span>
```

Comment: "*I want*" isn't a question; so where are you stuck? What do you need help with?

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: The bootstrap grid is not good enough because it design the layout in rows, while I want to design with columns

Comment: understood. also, the container needs a height.

Comment: @omer727 i think you need this [plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by manipulating the margins and padding in your css.

CSS:

```
.twitter-col {
    height:100% !important;
    min-height: 100% !important;
    background-color:lightSkyBlue;
    padding-bottom: 1000px;
    margin-bottom: -1000px;
}

.other-col {
    height:50% !important;
    min-height: 50% !important;
    background-color:red;
    padding-bottom: 500px;
    margin-bottom: -500px;
}

.other-other-col {
    height:100% !important;
    min-height: 100% !important;
    background-color:green;
    padding-bottom: 700px;
    margin-bottom: -700px;
}
```

Here is a [demo](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/epKdXJ)